# Concatenation of variable and String wrong

Tags: javascript, html, json

I would like to pass an argument to another page but it turns out that it's undefined.

getAccount() returns a list of json. Firstly, I display those json objects one by one on HTML and when the user clicks each, the accDetail[i].accNo is set as local storage and will be passed to next page.

```
var accDetail=getAccounts();


for(var i =0;i<accDetail.length;i++) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+='<a href="accountdetails.html" onclick="getAcc('+accDetail[i].accNo+')">'+accDetail[i].accNo +'</a>'+' '+ accDetail[i].accType+' '+ accDetail[i].balance+'<br>';
```

}

This is the function to set the item as local storage.

```
function getAcc(item)
{
    localStorage.setItem("accNo",item); }
```

It does not display the value I want, is the way I concatenate it wrong?

Comment: try `localStorage["accNo"]` or `localStorage.getItem('accNo');`

Comment: Don't write code like this. Don't build HTML as huge strings. Use a templating language, or some kind of framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onclick` handler is going to be *literally* `getAcc(accDetail[i].accNo)` (try viewing in Inspect Element), which won't work because `accDetail` is not defined in the event handler. You need to change your Javascript so that it writes `getAcc(0)`, `getAcc(1)`, etc where 0, 1 are the different `accNo`.

Here is a small example I wrote, hopefully you can extend it to solve your problem:

```
var accNo = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  for(var i = 0;i < accNo.length; i++) {
    var line = '<a href="accountdetails.html" onclick="getAcc(' + accNo[i] + ')">' + accNo[i] + '</a> <br>';
    console.log(line);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += line;
  }
```

Comment: why op didn't get the message `localStorgae is not defined`

Comment: What if I want to pass in a variable i.e. accDetail[i].accNo instead of the int e.g. 1,2,3?  Any way to do so?

Comment: Now it's not undefined but the value set to localStorage is not the value I want.

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure your function getting correct value

Try Using window object instead

```
function getAcc(item)
{
    localStorage.setItem("accNo",item); 
}

Replace with
```

> function getAcc(item)
>       {
>         console.log(item); //**Please check you get item correct not undefined**
>         window.accNo = item; 
>       }
>
> And whereever you want just use **window.accNo**